# Haskell - Why is it not working? (IO Action wth Lists)

Tags: list, haskell, io, return, monads

```
combinationIO :: Int -> [a] -> IO [[a]]
combinationIO 0 _ = return [[]]
combinationIO _ [] = return []
combinationIO n (x:xs) = do res <- (map (x:) (combinationIO (n-1) xs)) ++ (combinationIO n xs)
                          putStrLn $ (show n) ++ show " : (" ++ show (x,xs) ++ show ") = " ++ show res
                          return res
```

I saw this example (below) on some site, and I wondered how it works so I put some IO actions in it. However, ghci gives me a type error. What is the problem?

```
combination2 :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
combination2 0 _ = [[]]
combination2 _ [] = []
combination2 n (x:xs) = (map (x:) (combination2 (n-1) xs)) ++ (combination2 n xs)
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: If your code is indeed exactly as you put it here, then you have an indentation problem: `putStrLn` and `return` must be indented exactly at the level where `res <-` starts.

Answer (score 3):

The major problem is that `map` and `++` work on `[a]`, not `IO [a]`. I think what you wanted was something like this:

```
combinationIO :: Show a => Int -> [a] -> IO [[a]]
combinationIO 0 _ = return [[]]
combinationIO _ [] = return []
combinationIO n (x:xs) = do
  res1 <- combinationIO (n-1) xs
  res2 <- combinationIO n xs
  let res = (map (x:) res1) ++ res2
  putStrLn $ (show n) ++ " : (" ++ (show (x,xs)) ++ ") = " ++ (show res)
  return res
```

Comment: Or `(\res1 res2 -> map (x:) res1 ++ res2) <$> combinationIO (n-1) xs <*> combinationIO n xs`.